# Windows phone 8.1 get image from imageview to BitmapImage

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to take an image from -

```
<Image x:Name="ImagePreview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="492" Margin="10,10,0,0" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" />
```

ImagePreview is used to preview images with added filters like grayScale, black&white or cropped original images. The purpose of all of that is to save on phone edited image.

Comment: ImagePreview.Source will give the image

Comment: Tryed that with var newImg=ImagePreview.Source;  Then i get Image source type variable and i don't know how to convert it to Bitmap or save it on phone.

Comment: You have to just cast it to `BitmapImage` like this  `BitmapImage image = Image.Source as BitmapImage;`

Comment: Thank you didn't know i can do it like that. But i have new problem. When i chose to save unedited image, image is created but when i try to save image with grayScale filter image is null.

Comment: Solved. It was WriteableBitmap type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks for user @LovetoCode . To get image you need to cast it from imagePreview.

WriteableBitmap newImg = ImagePreview.Source as WriteableBitmap;

or for bitmap :
BitmapImage newImg = ImagePreview.Source as BitmapImage;